# highcharts.js and highstock.js conflict

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with highcharts and when it gets to funnels if highcharts.js and highstock.js are both included on the same page the funnel does not work.

After googling I found that a workaround is to use the bandled version of one and the non-bundled version of the other, which would be good but I believe this cannot be done because I cannot find bundled and non-bundled versions anymore.

So, having failed to do the above, does anyone know a workaround on how to get them both to work together on the same page?

Comment: You can add highcharts.js and highstock.js references in your config.json file. Then, use the gulpfile to bundle them together in vendors.js. In this way you will be able to use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wt75vxyo/)**